# Typo when dismissing comment flags as moderator

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, comment-flags, spelling

Perhaps a minor issue, but the text that accompanies this action reads **"comment flag dimissed"** [sic]:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops; thanks - fixed next deploy.